# Отладчик пропускает строку

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    auto foo = []()  -> int {};
    auto bar = [i]() -> int {};
    auto ptr1 = foo; // <-- пропускает
    auto ptr2 = bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Почему отладчик пропускает 4 строку, а 5 выполняет?

Comment: Может в режиме Release отлаживаете?

Comment: @Zealint Debug + я ставлю точку останова и иду прямо по строкам

Comment: Как-то связано с наличием захвата переменных в `[]`. Я думаю, отладчик просто выкидывает строки, которые не приводят к изменению видимого поведения. Хотя при отключенной оптимизации, имхо, не должен. Но может тут какой-то нюанс из-за лямбд.

Comment: Полагаю, что не этот случай, но такое может быть иногда, когда были правки файла. Даже если не в этом месте, а выше, что сдвинуло строки. Скорее всего вы про это знаете и это не тот случай. (Речь про правки после запуска приложения.)

Answer (score 2):

Ничего особенно странного. Компилятор имеет право выкидывать «мёртвый» код, то есть, код, который не приводит к видимым пользователем эффектам.

Для `foo`, лямбда без списка захвата есть просто указатель на статическую функцию, поэтому компилятору легче заметить, что строка `auto ptr1 = foo;` бесполезна (даже в `Debug`-режиме, да). Для `bar` это немного сложнее, так что в отладочном режиме компилятор, возможно, не выполняет эту оптимизацию.

Таким образом, отладчик не останавливается на этой строчке (`auto ptr1 = foo;`) по очень простой причине: *эта строка не сгенерировала никакого кода*.

Что именно выбрасывает компилятор при оптимизации, нигде не определено. В `Release`-режиме компилятор старается выбросить как можно больше, чтобы улучшить программу, но в `Debug`-режиме более сложный код остаётся для удобства отладки. В случае `bar` у вас создание (ненужного) объекта, содержащего лямбду, и компилятор решил немного помочь вам и не выбрасывать этот код (хотя и имел полное право).

---

В `Release`-режиме компилятор VS 2015 замечает, что весь ваш код по существу не нужен, так что реальный ассемблерный код функции `main` выглядит просто как

```
xor eax, eax
ret 0
```

Comment: не совсем "указатель на статическую функцию", для лямбды тип авто ,скорее, "указатель на кусок кода", а поскольку лямбда пустая, то при присваивании это будет эквивалентно просто записи auto ptr1; (в чистом виде это даст ошибку, но на строках вида `int i;` дебагер тоже не остановится)

Comment: @goldstar_labs: Для лямбды без захваченных переменных это именно статическая функция.

Comment: @goldstar_labs: http://ideone.com/MjaXbr

Comment: это немного терминологический момент. Стандарт допускает преобразование лямбд без захвата к указателю на функцию, однако создаваемым объектом будет все равно лямбда. Если глянуть дизасм в студии, то получим следующее:  `call <lambda_d3659b64280fabde1ff41f1e7f480259>::operator int (__cdecl*)(void)`, что есть каст лямбды к указателю.

Comment: @goldstar_labs: Это да, согласен. (Но только в Debug-режиме.) Тем не менее, семантически лямбда без списка захвата является статический функцией, и компилятору намного легче сообразить, что её можно выкинуть.

Answer (score 1):

Какое у вас IDE?
Возможно вы добавили строчку которую пропускает и не скомпилировали, а сразу запустили дебаг. Тк в компилированая версия не содержит эту строчку, он ее пропускает.